# Alert displays the wrong message when running the code

Tags: javascript

I am following a Javascript track on Teamtreehouse and I trying to make a game. It asks the user to guess a number between 1 and 6 and. The user can either guess the number, type smaller one and get another chance, type a bigger one and get another chance or not guess it at all.

```
var correctGuess = false;
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) +1;
    var guess = prompt("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 6. What is it?");

    if (parseInt(guess) === randomNumber) {

        correctGuess = true;}

        else if (parseInt(guess) < randomNumber) {
            var guessMore = prompt("Try again! The value I am thinking of is lower than " + guess);
            if (parseInt(guessMore) === randomNumber ) { 
                correctGuess =true;}

        } else if (parseInt(guess) > randomNumber) {
            var guessLess = prompt("Try again! The number I am thinking of is smaller than " + guess);
            if (parseInt(guessLess) === randomNumber) {

                correctGuess = true; }
            }
        

        if ( correctGuess) {


            alert("Yey!");
        } else {
            alert("Better luck next time! The number was " + randomNumber);
        };
```

Although the code seems fine to me, every 1 our of 5 times (let's say) it displays an anomaly (although the user the guessed the number, it runs the else statement; or it asks you for a smaller number only to find out that the result was in fact a bigger number etc). You have to run to run the code a few times to see what I mean. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check out your prompts for your else if statements.  They both say that the value you are thinking of is lower/smaller than the guess value.

Comment: this code works....you just have a typo: "lower" should be "larger"

Comment: I've been staring at this code for 3 hours and I couldn't see the typo. I need a break. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem with:

> or it asks you for a smaller number only to find out that the result
>   was in fact a bigger number etc)

This is due to the fact that you have both "lower than" and "smaller than" in your conditional statement.  I changed "lower than" to "greater than".

```
   else if (parseInt(guess) < randomNumber) {
            var guessMore = prompt(
            "Try again! The value I am thinking of is greater than " + guess);
            if (parseInt(guessMore) === randomNumber ) { 
                correctGuess =true;}
    } 
   else if (parseInt(guess) > randomNumber) {
            var guessLess = prompt(
            "Try again! The number I am thinking of is smaller than " + guess);
            if (parseInt(guessLess) === randomNumber) {

                correctGuess = true; }
            }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7yhhfv6g/4/

Comment: Oh, such a stupid mistake. Nothing wrong with the code itself, I misspelled a word. Thank you so much, now it works perfectly.

Comment: Don't feel bad, I stared at that for probably 5 minutes stepping through the code trying to find it.  :)